# Error trying to incorporate es2017 in webpack

Tags: reactjs, jsx, ecmascript-2017

I am trying to add es2017 to my webpack. My program compiles but I get a syntax error message [image] as in the previous picture. I believe I am missing something but I can not find what. I am trying to run the examples given at:

https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd

I placed each project inside a folder. I am using webpack because I am trying to make them run from a play-scala view (this is a play-scala project). The only thing that that view is doing is uploading the generated dragDropBundle.js.

Using:

npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2017

I installed es2017.

```
      {
             entry: './ui/dragDrop/index.js',
             output: { path: __dirname + '/public/compiled/dragDrop', filename: 'dragDropBundle.js' },
             module: {
            loaders: [
                { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel-loader', include: /ui/, query: { presets: ['es2017', 'react'] } },
               { test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract( "style", "css!sass") }
      ]
   },
    plugins: [
         new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
        ]
      }
```

Comment: Could you please share a exact error or post your jsx component code

Comment: Could you show your .babelrc?